# Layout 3 image links in a row HTML

Tags: css, html

[image]

Hi, I'm making a website and i need to have some image links laid out like they are in the image above. The grey rectangles are placeholders for where the images would be, they are all the same size (275 x 186) and need a margin in between them all. I also need to be able to add in more that 6 images.

I can't seem to get them to line up properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? If you show some code, we may be able to help you. Have you looked at Twitter Bootstrap? It's a good framework for layouts like this: http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way to do this is to use the "float" property of CSS.  here is how I would approach this problem.

1. create a div that has width of "275px + border-size" x 3
2. within this div add all your images with size 275 x 186 plus borders
3. assign the css property "float:left" to each image.

<

```
style>
    div.wrapper{
    width: ("275 + YOUR border-size" x 3)px;
     }
    div.image{
    background-image: url(..path to your img);
    float: left
    }
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    ... add all your imgs here
    <div style="clear: both"></div> //need this one here to make the wrapper extend 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. is there any way i could have writing underneath the pictures in the center?

Comment: You need to create another div or span underneath the <div class="image></div> and put your text writings in it